# Wordpress custom post type: returning *all* values of a multiple select list field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, podscms

I am echoing all the custom field values from a custom post type (created with *Pods*) within the Wordpress loop in a dedicated php template (no Pods template). This works for all custom fields except for a `relationship / simple / multiple selection list` field. There only the first one of the multiple selected values is echoed/returned.

I am using this code in the php template:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $title = get_the_title();
  $image = get_the_post_thumbnail();
  $location = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'location', true);
  $types = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'types', true);
  etc.
```

Later on I am echoing all these values. The field I have the problem with is `types`:

When I echo `$types`, only the first selected value of that field is echoed/returned. I thought it  would probably be an array and tried `print_r($types)` to check that, but that also only displays one (the first selected) key/value pair, no array.

The field selection type is `multiple-select`, the format `checkboxes`, if that’s of any relevance.

Any ideas what I can do to get and display all selected values of that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ 
The last parameter which you have set to 'true' is to tell WP if you only want a single value returned. 
Try changing it to 'false'.  An array of the values should then be returned.

Comment: Pods stores our multi select values individually so they can be queried with WP_Query nicely :)